# seafile php file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, seafile-server

I have created a basic CRM system using CodeIgniter in PHP and are making use of Seafile-Serve Web API to store and retreive files locate on the same server that hosts the CRM. The following is a function I created to upload existing files to seafile using the post method defined in the api manual: https://manual.seafile.com/develop/web_api.html#upload-file-1

```
public function uploadFile($upload_link, $upload_file, $upload_filename){
    return $this->decode($this->post($upload_link,
        array(
            'file'  => new Curlfile('test.txt'),
            'filename'  => "test.txt",
            'parent_dir' => "/"
        )
    ));
}
```

Can I perhaps ask that someone point out the various things I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the problem? is it not working? is it returning an error?

Comment: It is not returning anything. If I can get an error response I can diagnose but there is no response. Right now I am concerned that the file handling is done incorrectly. This is done via a form post and I am sure the seafile api works fine, but am I sending the file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a lot of thing could be happening... did you tried to put `new Curlfile('test.txt')` into a separated variable and then `var_dump`/`die()` it to see if the file is really being "loaded" correctly? Also, are you passing the absolute path to that file?

Comment: The issue related to the filepath. Seafile is looking for the absolutepath and I was using the relative path.